# TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of null. I don't know how to resolve

Tags: react-hooks

My code is as below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    view: null,
    viewer: null,
    tasks: [],
    current_date: new Date(),
    selected_element_id: null,
    selected_element_status: "NotStarted",
    element_statuses: {},
  });


function objectTreeCreated(event) {
    let element_statuses = {};
    event.model.search(
      "Basic Wall",
      (dbIds) => {
        console.log(dbIds);
        event.model.getBulkProperties(dbIds, ["Category", "Length"], (elements) => {
          let filtered_elements = elements.filter((element) => element.properties.length === 2);
          filtered_elements.forEach((element) => {
            element_statuses[element.dbId.toString()] = "NotStarted";
          });
          setState({ element_statuses: element_statuses });
        });
      },
      null,
      ["name"]
    );
  }
```

I am trying to assign the value to variable element_statuses based on the dbIds which can be null to any value.

Comment: Where and how is `objectTreeCreated` called

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I have resolved the issue by using break statement and spread operator. Thanks once again. Regards